# How to make ACM style pdfs searchable?

Tags: font-encodings

When I create pdfs using the [ACM template](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates), searching for and copying umlauts doesn't work. Using `cmap` gives an error "fontenc already loaded". How can this be fixed?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\title{A Sample {\ttlit ACM} SIG Proceedings Paper in LaTeX}

\numberofauthors{1} 
\author{
\alignauthor
Ben Trovato\titlenote{Dr.~Trovato insisted his name be first.}\\
       \affaddr{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}\\
       \affaddr{1932 Wallamaloo Lane}\\
       \affaddr{Wallamaloo, New Zealand}\\
       \email{trovato@corporation.com}
}
\date{30 July 1999}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This paper provides a sample of a \LaTeX\ document which conforms to
the formatting guidelines for ACM SIG Proceedings.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Äöüß fiffy.

The \textit{proceedings} are the records of a conference.
ACM seeks to give these conference by-products a uniform,
high-quality appearance.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The developers of the class think that in the last 17 years no progress has been made with fonts.

In lines 1470--1492 they reproduce the package `ae.sty`, that is obsolete. You can add

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

to your preamble and solve the problem. The call of `cmap` is not needed.

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Do you think anyone will notice that I used a different font when they compile the conference proceedings?

Comment: @Arian They'll probably remove `\usepackage{lmodern}` if they recompile the document. But it's their business.

Answer (score 1):

While the selected answer works, *it changes the ACM template's font*.

Here's a solution which will not change the default font/formatting.

Simply add the following before `\begin{document}`:

```
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
```